# Регулярка для символа \ QRegExp

Tags: регулярные-выражения, qt, qt5, qtcreator

Поправьте пожалуйста регулярку вот эту:
`QRegExp PIDRegExp(attr + "Rev_(.+)[&\\]");`
Надо чтобы из этого: `G&Rev_1100\1` вытянулось вот это: `1100`
вместо символа `\` может быть еще символ `&` поэтому поставил `[&\\]`

Comment: А что сейчас-то захватывается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Qt регулярные выражения немного отличаются от привычных нам в PHP, C#, Python...

Чтобы с помощью регулярного выражения найти обратную косую черту, надо использовать 4 таких знака, так как в строках Qt могут быть экранированные последовательности:

```
QRegExp PIDRegExp(attr + "Rev_(.+)[&\\\\]"); 
PIDRegExp.setMinimal(true); // Отключаем жадность в Qt
```

Чтобы обойтись без "отключения жадности", можно использовать `[^&\\\\]+`, что  означает *всё, кроме & и \*:

```
QRegExp PIDRegExp(attr + "Rev_([^&\\\\]+)");
```

По-моему, такое выражение излишне, так как нужно извлечь цифры после `Rev_`.

```
QString str = "G&Rev_1100\\1";
QRegExp rxlen("Rev_(\\d+)");  // Тут обратная косая черта двойная
int pos = rxlen.indexIn(str);
QStringList list = rxlen.capturedTexts(); // Получаем массив захваченных подстрок
QString my_number = list[1];         // А вот и наше число
```

Comment: Эмм... Регистрозависимость и жадность — не одно и то же :) Тогда уж `QRegExp::setMinimal(bool minimal)` ([тынц](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qregexp.html#setMinimal)), чтобы совсем Qt-way.

Comment: Прошу прощения, это я не то вклеил :( Поправил.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос в том, по какому признаку из выражения выделяется `1100`, что это вообще за группа символов.

Если это всегда будут цифры, то наиболее очевидным способом будет явно обозначить это в регулярке: `G&Rev_(\d+)[&\\]1` (в группу попадёт одна или более цифр). Так будет в том числе нагляднее для человека, который этот код будет потом поддерживать.

Если символы могут быть любыми, лишь бы следом шла "закрывающая" черта, и использование `.*` было осознанно и неотвратимо, то фейлиться такое выражение может из-за жадности. Попробуйте вместо этого ленивый вариант типа `.*?`.

Впрочем, и ваш вариант должен был отработать нормально: жадно захватив в группу `1100\1`, регулярка понимает, что завершения `\1` никак не получается, и делает шаг назад. Таким образом дойдя до варианта `1100` и следующим за ним `\1`. Непонятно также, почему вы используете `*`. Может быть последовательность символов, а может быть сразу `G&Rev_\1`? Подумайте об этом самостоятельно :)